# How can I import from a usb webcam on the raspberry pi?

Tags: image, data-acquisition, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi as a webcam server and I need to import images into a Mathematica notebook on the raspberry pi. I tried using `CurrentImage[]` just to test it but I got an error just saying `$Failed` in Mathematica, and in my terminal it said

> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x6d 0x6d
>
> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x6d 0x6d
>
> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x6d 0x6d
>
> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x6d 0x6d

So then I rand `$ImagingDevices` in Mathematica and it said (Raspicam), then I tried

```
DeviceOpen["Raspicam"]
```

but it said

> DeviceOpen::noclass: A driver for Raspicam was not found on your
>
> local computer. Please add the driver directory to $Path or load it with Get.

But I'm not sure if that's necessary just yet. A few other things I tried didn't work, like `ImageCapture[]` and various permutations of `DeviceRead` but without being able to use `DeviceOpen` that won't work.

I think part of the problem might be that I'm using just a basic usb webcam and not the raspberry pi camera module so maybe Mathematica doesn't recognise it but I can capture images using the command fswebcam in my terminal on the raspberry pi so I think there's enough power to the device.

Comment: I met the same problem on my project, watching for answers.